# Mostrar datos en una tabla según la opción seleccionada de un select

Tags: php, html, mysql, modal

hola quiero que me ayuden con algo, ¿Cómo hago para mostrar información en una tabla según la opción de un select? tengo un código que abre un modal y muestra un select con producto de una tabla, pero no tengo la mínima idea de como obtener el valor de la opción seleccionada del select y que según ese id muestre la información del producto.
Les dejo el código del modal que tiene el select.

```
<div class="modal fade" id=modal tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Seleccione un Producto</h5>
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                     </button>
                        </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    
                    <select class="form-control" id="articulo" onchange="seleccionarLenguaje();">
                            
                            <?php
                               $v = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM articulo WHERE estado='activo'");
                               while($item=$v->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
                                   ?>
                                                               
                                  <option value="<?php print $item['idarticulo'];?>"><?php echo $item['nombre'];?></option>
                                <?php
  
                                  }
                                 
                            ?>
                          </select>
                         
                     </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que meter todo ese HTML entre etiquetas `<form></form>` y leer el dato enviado desde el `<select name="campo"><option value="33"/></select>` con `$_GET['campo']`. Algo así:

```
<form>
<select name="campo">
  <option value="33"/>
  <option value="34"/>
</select>
<button>Enviar</button>
</form>

<?php

echo $_GET['campo'];
```